# Rest WCF server "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." content larger than 64k

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, rest

The problem is related to WCF configuration hell, I have developed a wcf rest server and i will be needing it to use with iPhone and android client. Problem is that my custom configuration i think is not picking up because data larger than 64kb give `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` on client. Here is my code

- **Server Configurations:**

  ```
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="customHttpsBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" >
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2097151" />
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport proxyCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webHttpBehaviour">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
              automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"  faultExceptionEnabled="true"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="customServiceBehavior" >
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>

        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
      </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
  ```

**Server Method:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/content?contributorId={contributorId}&marketId={marketId}&fileExtension={fileExtension}",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ActionResult PostUerContent(string contributorId,int marketId,string fileExtension, Stream streamContent);
```

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceRoute serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute("api", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MobileAPI));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(serviceRoute);
}
```

**Client Side Code (.Net)**

```
Stream fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/desert_.jpg"), FileMode.Open);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://shaq.***.local/mobile/api/content?contributorId=10634&marketid=2&fileExtension=.jpg");
Stream serverStream = null;
try
{
    request.ContentType = "application/plain";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    request.SendChunked = true;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    serverStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
    while (true)
    {
        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            serverStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
     }

     request.GetResponse();

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { }
 finally
 {
     serverStream.Close();
     fileStream.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Please help me format it, i tried but it isn't happening, I am surely having a bad day :(

Comment: Can you try changing transferMode to Buffer (or other options) ...

Comment: Also please share HttpRuntime settings and <compiliation ?

Comment: Also check  IIS -> Request filtering (selecting ur wcf service) -> Edit Feature Settings -> Request Limit

Comment: Tried all of the above things but same issue!